# how to automatically populate other fields when town is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, auto-populate

I have 3 textboxes in a form - town, county and country. A list appears for town so the user can select from this list. When a town is selected I want the country and county textboxes to be populated. But when the town is selected, nothing appears in the other textboxes.

```
 function OnCheckIfTownValid<%= AddressType %>(result) {
        if(result.ID != -1){
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTownID.ClientID %>').value = result.ID;
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTown.ClientID %>').value = result.TownName;
            $('#<%= txtCountyID.ClientID %>').val(result.CountyID);
            $('#<%= txtCountryID.ClientID %>').val(result.CountryID);
            $('#<%= txtCounty.ClientID %>').val(result.County);
            $('#<%= txtCountry.ClientID %>').val(result.Country); 
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTownID.ClientID %>').value = "0";
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTown.ClientID %>').value = "";
        }
```

Here is what console.log returns:

```
[object Object] {CountryID: 529, CountyID: 11852, CreatedBy: "", CreatedDate: date, Element: null, ID: 437, IsActive: true, ModifiedBy: "", ModifiedDate: date, TownISO: "0", TownName: "Aberdeen", Zone: ""}
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      __type: "Lookups+Town",
      CountryID: 529,
      CountyID: 11852,
      CreatedBy: "",
      CreatedDate: [date] Thu Aug 13 2015 17:13:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),
      Element: null,
      ID: 437,
      IsActive: true,
      ModifiedBy: "",
      ModifiedDate: [date] Thu Aug 13 2015 17:13:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time),
      TownISO: "0",
      TownName: "Aberdeen",
      Zone: ""
   }
```

Comment: Can you do `console.log(result)` and put the o/p in the question

Comment: @Abhi where does console print to?

Comment: how you are getting **result**?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Try this:

```
function OnCheckIfTownValid<%= AddressType %>(result) {
        if(result.ID != -1){
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTownID.ClientID %>').value = result["ID"];
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTown.ClientID %>').value = result["TownName"];
            $('#<%= txtCountyID.ClientID %>').val(result["CountyID"]);
            $('#<%= txtCountryID.ClientID %>').val(result["CountryID"]);
            $('#<%= txtCounty.ClientID %>').val(result["County"]);
            $('#<%= txtCountry.ClientID %>').val(result["Country"]);
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTownID.ClientID %>').value = "0";
            document.getElementById('<%= txtAddTown.ClientID %>').value = "";
        }
```

You can also put a Console.Log(Result) in the function so you can see if result gets populated.

Edit: Link with more info: [Link here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/471799/jQuery-introduction-and-how-to-use-jQuery-with-ASP)

Comment: no that doesn't work. County and Country say undefined

Comment: What does console.log(Result) return, could you add it?

Comment: where do I find where console prints?

Comment: Press F12 go to tab console(IE) For Chrome same deal and Firefox as well I think

Comment: I pressed F12 but I don't see console

Comment: On what browser are you, include version number as well please.

Comment: I added the console.log to my question

Comment: It causes the error Unable to get property 'CountyID' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @user123456789 Check out the image, it shows how a console looks like in Chrome